# HOWTO: Decode a single byte into a string using different encodings

Tags: vb.net, unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I would like to represent a single Byte into different types of encodings like unicode, UTF-8, ASCII and Operating System's current ANSI code page, so how could I do this in vb.net?

For example, suppose I have a byte array with numbers from 0 to 255 and its length of 256:

```
Dim byteArray(255) As Byte

byteArray(0)=0
byteArray(1)=1
byteArray(2)=2
...
byteArray(255)=255
```

I am not sure at all if below code accomplishes what I want. Anyone could confirm me if it is correct? I am not expert in this area...

```
Dim unicode_string as String
Dim utf8_string as String
Dim ascii_string as String
Dim default_string as String

For i as Integer = 0 to byteArray.length - 1
   ' As Unicode is UTF-16, uses 2 bytes, we construct a new byte array with its second byte to zero.
   unicode_string = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(New Byte() {byteArray(i), 0})
   utf8_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, i, 1)
   ascii_string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray, i, 1)
   default_string = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray, i, 1)

   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", unicode_string, utf8_string, ascii_string, default_string)
Next
```

Comment: Are you looking for a review? `is below correct?` sounds like it... If not what's the specific problem and what is not working as you didn't specify this either.

Comment: Anyway what you're asking is impossible. UTF-8 and UTF-16 use multiple bytes to encode a character.

Comment: @roeland so If I want to see which character corresponds to a single byte in different encodings (ascii, utf-8, etc...), are you saying it is not possible? or only in case of UTF-8 and UTF-16 is not possible? but unicode is possible (and it is UTF-16), right? by adding a second byte to zero for example, why can't I do the same for UTF-8, UTF-16? because they use a variable number of bytes to encode a character and this number cannot be known previously before decoding?

Comment: @user1624552 did you not see my comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb.net: Encoding byte array into string using Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873332/vb-net-encoding-byte-array-into-string-using-unicode)

Comment: @user1624552 I think you just need to start with a tutorial covering the basics of encoding and decoding text.

Comment: Read up on what [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) actually are and how they work. For instance, in UTF-8, only 1 codepoint has a null byte when encoded (U+0000), and in UTF-16, not all Unicode codepoints have encoded null bytes. So you can't blindly add null bytes and expect things to work correctly. The bytes are structured in specific ways.  Also see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).